# show a website loading image using only CSS (not Javascript or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i put a logo and a loading image when a user open the website

when the user open the website the logo appear with a loading image than the home page appear after a certain moment like this website
    http://www.theprofessionalslb.com/

**and it possible to do that without using javascript or jquery only in css?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can animate with pure CSS using the `animate` property.

For example, if you would want `#img1` to show first, and `#img2` to show after, you can set an `animation-delay` on your second image and make that equal to the `animation-duration` of your first:

```
#img1 {
    ...
    animation-duration: 2s;
    ...
}
#img2 {
    ...
    animation-delay: 2s;
    ...
}
```

Then in your animation you can animate e.g. the `opacity` property to simulate a fade-in effect.

More on CSS Animations [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

**EDIT**
I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/of298r0L/2/) doing what you want.
For support in more browsers, please advice [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation).

Comment: and how to do that when a user open the website the animation appear and than the home page open

Comment: See updated EDIT. There is no reason to bloat your page with unnecessary JavaScript. @mhmd

Comment: what browser (and version) are you using? I'll update the fiddle with support for your browser, since I think that's the issue here.

Comment: Please check again [here](https://jsfiddle.net/of298r0L/2/) (don't forget to click "Run" in the upper left corner)

Comment: sry but it didn't work what the name of this if i want do more search

Comment: weird. I've added all support for cross-browser functionality based on canisue.com specs. You can try a different browser still. If you want to do more research, search on "CSS Splash Screen", for I think that resembles your example the most. A nice tutorial can be found [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/apple-style-splash-screen-jquery/).

Comment: Great, good to hear! Please don't forget to mark this answer with "Accepted" if you're satisfied with the results. Good luck coding =)

Answer (score 0):

Use loader image and apply it to body. Show the image till page load and when page is ready remove the image.

```
jQuery( window ).load( function(){
  //show the image here.
});
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
  //hide the image here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way they did it, it's handled by jQuery-Animations, something like this:

```
// Fade-In logo
$('#logo').fadeIn(2000, function() {
  // When done, fade-in the slogan
  $('#slogan').fadeIn(1400, function() {
    // When this is done, wait 1s and then fade both out
    $('#logo, #slogan').delay(1000).fadeOut(2000, function() {
      // Finally fade-in the content
      $('#content').fadeIn(2000);
    });
  });
});
```

The first argument of the `fadeIn`-method is the animation-time, the second argument is the callback-function, that gets executed after the animation is done. For more information see its [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/).

This technique assumes either, that your animated elements are either set to `opacitiy: 0` in their CSS, or that you set them hidden in your JS:

```
$('#logo, #slogan, #content').fadeOut(0);
```

or:

```
$('#logo, #slogan, #content').hide();
```

---

You could also use plain CSS for this, where you would do *something* like this:

```
#logo, #slogan, #content {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeInAndOut {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    50%  { opacity: 1; }
    75%  { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

#logo {
  animation-name: fadeInAndOut;
  animation-duration: 6400ms;
}

#slogan {
  animation-name: fadeInAndOut;
  animation-duration: 4400ms;
  animation-delay: 2000ms;
}

#content {
  transition: opacity 2000ms ease-out 6400ms;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

---

Please be aware that both examples are untested and should just give you an idea. You will probably need to also use the `-webkit-keyframes` prefixed version for the animation and also if you want the animation timings to be visually perfect, you'd need two separate `fadeInAndOut`-keyframes for both.